# Combining two c++ files in Xcode for OpenCV (Use of undeclared identifier CVSquares)

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, opencv

I am trying to merge [OpenCVCircles](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVCircles) and [OpenCVSquares](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSquares) for a project. If I open them directly from the Xcode project files (independently) they work fine, but if I move the CVSquares.h and CVSquares.cpp files to the OpenCVCircles project, it starts complaining: "Use of undeclared identifier CVSquares". This happens in CVWrapper.mm (see problematic line towards the end):

```
#import "CVWrapper.h"
#import "CVCircles.h"
#import "CVSquares.h"
#import "UIImage+OpenCV.h"

    //remove 'magic numbers' from original C++ source so we can manipulate them from obj-C
#define TOLERANCE 0.3
#define THRESHOLD 50
#define LEVELS 9
#define ACCURACY 0

@implementation CVWrapper

+ (NSMutableArray*) detectedCirclesInImage:(UIImage*) image
{
    double dp = 1;
    double minDist = 10;
    double param1 = 100;
    double param2 = 30;
    int min_radius = 1;
    int max_radius = 30;

    return [[self class] detectedCirclesInImage:image
                                             dp:dp
                                        minDist:minDist
                                         param1:param1
                                         param2:param2
                                     min_radius:min_radius
                                     max_radius:max_radius];
}


+ (NSMutableArray*) detectedCirclesInImage:(UIImage*)image
                                 dp:(CGFloat)dp
                            minDist:(CGFloat)minDist
                             param2:(CGFloat)param2

{
    double param1 = 100;
    int min_radius = 1;
    int max_radius = 30;

    return [[self class] detectedCirclesInImage:image
                                             dp:dp
                                        minDist:minDist
                                         param1:param1
                                         param2:param2
                                     min_radius:min_radius
                                     max_radius:max_radius];
}

+ (NSMutableArray*) detectedCirclesInImage:(UIImage*)image
                                 dp:(CGFloat)dp
                            minDist:(CGFloat)minDist
                             param2:(CGFloat)param2
                         min_radius:(int)min_radius
                         max_radius:(int)max_radius
{
    double param1 = 100;

return [[self class] detectedCirclesInImage:image
                                         dp:dp
                                    minDist:minDist
                                     param1:param1
                                     param2:param2
                                 min_radius:min_radius
                                 max_radius:max_radius];
}



+ (NSMutableArray*) detectedCirclesInImage:(UIImage*)image
                                 dp:(CGFloat)dp
                            minDist:(CGFloat)minDist
                             param1:(CGFloat)param1
                             param2:(CGFloat)param2
                         min_radius:(int)min_radius
                         max_radius:(int)max_radius
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIImage* modifiedImage = nil;
    cv::Mat matImage = [image CVMat];
        int num_circles = 0;
    matImage = CVCircles::detectedCirclesInImage
    (matImage,  dp,  minDist, param1, param2, min_radius, max_radius, &num_circles);
    modifiedImage = [UIImage imageWithCVMat:matImage];
    NSLog(@"n circles: %i",num_circles);
    [array addObject:modifiedImage];
    [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:num_circles]];
    NSLog(@"array: %@, %@",[array objectAtIndex:0],[array objectAtIndex:1]);
    return array;
}



+ (UIImage*) detectedSquaresInImage:(UIImage*) image
{
    //if we call this method with no parameters,
    //we use the defaults from the original c++ project
    return [[self class] detectedSquaresInImage:image
                                      tolerance:TOLERANCE
                                      threshold:THRESHOLD
                                         levels:LEVELS
                                       accuracy:ACCURACY];

}


+ (UIImage*) detectedSquaresInImage:(UIImage*) image
                          tolerance:(CGFloat)  tolerance
                          threshold:(NSInteger)threshold
                             levels:(NSInteger)levels
                           accuracy:(NSInteger)accuracy

{
    //NSLog (@"detectedSquaresInImage");
    UIImage* result = nil;
    cv::Mat matImage = [image CVMat];

    //ERROR IS ON THIS LINE
    matImage = CVSquares::detectedSquaresInImage (matImage, tolerance, threshold, levels, accuracy);


    result = [UIImage imageWithCVMat:matImage];
    //NSLog (@"detectedSquaresInImage result");

    return result;

}


@end
```

I have the impression that I'm double defining something, missing .mm in some files, or the like but I have been struggling with this for the whole day and I can't make it work (today was my first time with C++). Any help would be much appreciated.

PS: Thanks to foundry (whoever he/she is) for the 2 awesome plug & play projects!

Answer (score 0):

Ended up pasting all the CVSquares.cpp code into the CVCircles.cpp code (as well as the CVSquares.h into the CVCircles.h) and calling:

```
matImage = CVCircles::detectedSquaresInImage (matImage, tolerance, threshold, levels, accuracy);
```

Couldn't get it to work otherwise. Hope it helps!

Comment: PS: Found another solution which was creating a new c++ file, calling it CVSquares and then copying all the original CVSquares code in there. Now it works for some strange reason...